# Search has failed me. I hang my head in shame

Tags: discussion, search

I'm certain we had a question about Star Wars book covers, more specifically about whether there was ever a version of the Star Wars cover/poster that had Leia doing the archetypal Frazetta [leg-cling](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LegCling) with Luke.

Has this question been deleted? or did I simply dream it?

[image]

Comment: There are 42 deleted questions containing the word "Leia". I haven't read them all, but a quick scan through the titles suggests that yes, you simply dreamed it.

Comment: You might not like that outcome, but sure it wasn't [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/44925/49) you remember?

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach - No, that's not it. The question was very specifically about Leia clutching Luke's leg. The OP wanted to know where they'd seen it. They were adamant that they'd seen a version where she was ***grabbing*** his leg, not just in front of it

Comment: Nope, I'm only remembering that question about posters and it has an answer that includes leg clinging, but not by them. I think I'm just merging the memory together. After reading it, it's got the fuzzy details.

Comment: FWIW, the question exists on reddit, so maybe you read it there?

Comment: “ I hang my head in shame”. You must now walk out into the frozen tundra and await nightfall. If the gods see fit to spare you, you may live to see the dawn.

Comment: Perhaps a deleted question? Have you tried the SEDE? Regardless, you probably dreamed about Leia.